# How to use StAX parser with umlauts (ÄÜÖ)?

Tags: java, xml, unicode, encoding, stax

I'm using the StreamReaderDelegate and want to use umlauts (ÄÜÖ).

My initialisation of the StAX parser:

```
public class GraphDataStreamReader extends StreamReaderDelegate {
  public GraphDataStreamReader(XMLStreamReader streamReader) throws XMLStreamException {
    super(streamReader);
  }
  ...
}
```

....

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
graphSR = new GraphDataStreamReader(
            factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(xmlFile)));
```

- In the XMLFile: Grenzübergang Mesenich LU->DE
- Out getAttributeValue(x): GrenzÃ¼bergang Mesenich LU->DE

My XML File is marked with UTF-8 (also tried 16, 32).

What can i do?

Comment: Looks like a proper encoded ü in UTF-8 displayed as ISO-Latin-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileReader` uses the platform's default character encoding and will corrupt the file content if your XML file uses a different encoding.

Use a `FileInputStream` instead:

```
factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xmlFile))
```

Comment: That was fast and solved it :) (only i also need to change the UTF to 8).

Comment: @besnep in addition to using a FileInputStream, createXMLStreamReader() has a [second parameter for encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createXMLStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29), you can (and should) specify your encoding there.

Comment: @eis That's not right. The StreamReaderDelegate doesn't have this second parameter. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.html

Comment: @eis: No, you should of course not have to specify the character encoding when reading an XML file. The character encoding is specified in the XML header and the parser will use whatever encoding is specified in the XML file itself. Specifying the encoding can be useful if you e.g. get the XML stream from a network connection and the encoding is specified using an HTTP header, but *not* when reading an XML file from disk.

Comment: @besnep I didn't say StreamReaderDelegate has it, I said createXMLStreamReader() has it, and I even gave a link to it. It's a method of XMLInputFactory.

Comment: @jarnbjo ok, fair enough.

Comment: @eis Totally right. But you're missing the point that i'm using the StreamReaderDelegate (really clear in my question above). Therefor your answer is useless. Just saying.

Comment: @besnap ... what? Please re-read your own question. You're using XMLInputFactory in your code when you're calling your extension of StreamReaderDelegate. Just saying. :D